# Handling refund notifications for consumable in-app-purchases

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit, receipt-validation

According to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/handling_refund_notifications), to identify the transaction, productId and relevant dates, we should "Find the most-recent transaction ***for the product_id*** in the unified_receipt.latest_receipt_info".

My question is **how do I find out the product_id?** My app has multiple consumable in-app-purchases.

One **option I was exploring was to [locally receipt validate]**[2](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html) the receipt blob in the [responseBody.unified_receipt.latest_receipt field](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/unified_receipt). But I need the [identifierForVendorId](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor) for that, and the identifierForVendorId isn't sent in the [request](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/responsebody).

I am **not mentioning remote receipt validation** because Apple has clearly stated in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/handling_refund_notifications) that "Refunded transactions are not present in the JSON response when you call the verifyReceipt endpoint with a receipt that contains refunded transactions, except for auto-renewable subscriptions.".

Thank you!
Looking forward to hear how others have implemented refunds for their non-subscription products.

Comment: Why do you need the `identifierForVendor`? The product ids are your product ids. You should know what they are.

Comment: I have lots of product_ids. Want to treat it as an opaque string. Additionally, we wouldn't know which consumable product_id got refunded if the request has multiple receipts.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? Do you have your own server where you check against this?